# "Take us away" or "take it away"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I was recently at a conference where the lecturer was introduced by a native speaker and I believe he said "Dr. X, take us away!".

I thought the idiom was "take it away" https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20it%20away , is it also idiomatic to say instead "take us away"?

The native speaker was from the Southern part of the US

Comment: This "lecturer" - are you sure he wasn't the bus driver?

Answer (score 1):

Idioms are often modified by native speakers in informal speech. The essential part of the idiom is 'taking away', meaning 'accepting the transfer of control or direction and start *something*'. What is started might be the lecture, or, as natives will immediately understand, the 'taking' of the audience on a journey (hopefully) to greater understanding and enlightenment. It might have seemed rather egotistical if that person had said 'take *me* away!' (and also liable to be misunderstood). 'Take it away!' might seem a little too casual and also mainly related to a musical performance.

Comment: Thank you Michael and @RobbieGoodwin for your insights! It makes sense that people keep modifying the idiom, English is a living language after all. But would you say you've heard this before? Even if it is a neologism, would you say it sounds somewhat natural? Since I'm not a native speaker, it's quite hard for me to make these sort of judgements. Thanks again!

Comment: To me Michael goes too far sideways, while missing the real point. Who believes 'accepting the transfer of control or direction and start something' will ever work? Either way, I suggest 'take us away' is now at best a neologism, though if that gains currency it might in future become an idiom.

Comment: No, Flen. Never noticed it before; doesn't sound at all natural; English is a living language and even so it's almost unheard of for a native speaker to modify an idiom as clichéd as "take it away." Much more likely to be a slip of his tongue or your ear! How certain can you be about what you heard?